# Why does redis-py not have geo extensions?

Tags: python, redis, redis-py

I installed redis-py2.10.5 via pip. It installed without errors. However, I am unable to access the geo related functions.

```
In [1]: import redis

In [2]: r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)

In [3]: r.set('foo', 'bar')
Out[3]: True

In [4]: r.geoadd('Sicily 13.361389 38.115556 "Palermo" 15.087269 37.502669')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-4e252ecb84dd> in <module>()
----> 1 r.geoadd('Sicily 13.361389 38.115556 "Palermo" 15.087269 37.502669')

AttributeError: 'StrictRedis' object has no attribute 'geoadd'
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an open issue in official github repo: ['StrictRedis' object has no object called 'geoadd'](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/issues/851)

From issue comments you have two choices:

> You can either use the [fork](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/redispy/3.0.0) mentioned in that issue (preferred) or `pip install git+https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py.git`.

Answer (score 0):

r.execute_command('Sicily 13.361389 38.115556 "Palermo" 15.087269 37.502669')

it worked.